# core data stack ,,No visible @interface for 'coreDataStack' declares the selector 'defaultStack'

Tags: ios, objective-c, compiler-errors

i am new to objective c and i am following a tutorial in treeHouse 
i did exactly the same as the video 
here is the error 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPa9i.png)

could you help me 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUWyT.png)

i am using the last version of x code

Comment: Don't put your code in links/images. Put it in the post, in text form.

Answer (score 1):

First, classes should start with capital letters.

Second, the error is because you haven't declared that method in the class's `@interface`.

You are also importing a ".m" file, which you should never do.   The method needs to be declared in the `@interface` of the class and you should *only* import the `*.h`

Follow the naming guidelines, fix **all warnings**, and practice, practice, practice.

Comment: actually i did     ‏#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>


(at)interface coreDataStack : NSObject
+(instancetype)defaultStack;
(at)property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
(at)property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
(at)property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;
- (void)saveContext;
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory;



@end

Answer (score 1):

The problem is similar to what @bbum was saying. Definitely follow the suggestion that classes should start with capital letters. The reason this is important, especially in this case, is to eliminate the ambiguity between the *class* `coreDataStack` and the *object* `coreDataStack`.

When you're attempting to do `coreDataStack *coreDataStack = [coreDataStack defaultStack];` the compiler is trying to find the method on the instance level, when your implementation is at the class level. Proper casing guidelines would change this line and eliminate the ambiguity:

```
CoreDataStack *coreDataStack = [CoreDataStack defaultStack];
```

Or, if you're too lazy to do it the right way, just change the name of your object in this case to anything other than `coreDataStack`.